# Change specific parameters within a Pytorch Model layer according to a true false mask

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

Im trying to change specific values within the tensor of e.g. the bias of my convolutional layer according to a true false mask.

```
Mask = True/False mask
param = conv1.bias
benign = replacement tensor (of shape param, but i also only want the values where mask = True)
```

**What ive tried**

```
torch.where(mask.unsqueeze(0),benign,param)
```

-> Gives the correct Tensor, but doesnt operate/change the actual values of my bias but returns a new Tensor

```
param[mask.bool()] = benign[mask.bool()]
```

-> Throws the runtime error: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

```
param.masked_fill(mask.unsqueeze(0),benign[mask])
```

->doesnt accept non 0-dim values as fill value

How can i archieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your first try was almost correct, but as you mentioned torch.where only creates a new tensor.
You can set that new tensor as the bias after converting it to a nn.Parameter, as follows:

```
conv1.bias  = torch.nn.parameter.Parameter(data=torch.where(mask.unsqueeze(0),benign,param), requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. Is there a way however to do this dynamically based on the layer?
E.g.: i have the layer names conv1.bias and conv1.weight.
How do i implement this without hardcoding the names?

Comment: Do you mean, you have b=conv1.bias and w=conv1.weight and you want to do it based on the names b and w, not on conv1?

Comment: I mean that i want to do this operation for multiple layers, for which i get the names of via list.

e.g [conv1.bias,conv1,weight,fc1.bias]

And with the approach above i would need to hardcode the path, which is not possible when i only get the list of names during runtime